# How to use the useSelect component correctly

Tags: block-editor, rest-api, react

I've been getting into WordPress block programming for a few weeks now, but I'm still not entirely clear on how useSelect works even though I've followed almost the entire official library.

This is my simple test code from the edit.js file, and I don't understand why useSelect runs constantly even when adding a simple letter on a paragraph block that doesn't pertain to the block I'm building.

No dependency is passed inside [], so how come it still executes?

```
export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const posts = useSelect(
        (select) => {
            const posts = select("core").getEntityRecords("postType", "post", {
                per_page: -1,
                status: ["publish", "private"],
            });
            console.log("Posts: ", posts);
            return posts;
        },
        [],
    ) ?? [];
    console.log(posts);
    
    return (
        <p {...useBlockProps()}>
            {__("New Block", "text-domain")}
        </p>
    );
}
```